# pushing to github from work "Bad file number" error

Tags: git, github, msysgit

I got msysgit installed at my computer. And I configured it to work with github at home, where everything went fine.
At work it doesn't:

```
D:\rails_tutorial_projects\first_app>git push --verbose
Pushing to git@github.com:Monomachus/DemoRubyApp.git
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I read about Smart HTTP Support https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support 
But it seems that it doesn't work too. I make clone and all that stuff without problems but when I try to push changes back to github this is where the same problems came in.
My msysgit version is git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0

Please help me with this awkward situation.

Comment: You get an SSH error if you're using HTTP(S) too?

Comment: If you mean by this cloning using HTTP or HTTPS than yes I do get the same error.

Comment: Try looking at http://help.github.com/key-setup-redirect

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This error is also caused by attempting to push/clone etc. through a proxy server. Since you mentioned you are at a business, do they use a proxy server there?

The error is git literally saying, "hey, the file isn't there", because it can't get through the proxy server.

Comment: I have the same problem sometimes, and working through direct broadband connection. E.g. I run the same command "git clone ..." and get 2 times this error from 3 attempt in 1 minute. Also sometimes github.com website's page doesn't load at all for about few seconds and shows error "...could not connect to github.com", but if F5 is hit, then page loads immediately. Seems to be packets lost.

Comment: When this happened to me just now, I switched to surfing via my tethered Android (different network alltogether), everything was resolved ... but then I got the same error 10 seconds later. I guess the problem can also be momentarily glitches at github.com