# Joyent no.de: cant ssh/git push into my node.js machine

Tags: git, node.js, ssh, joyent

I get:

> ssh: connect to host switchboard1.no.de port 34726: Bad file number
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

As the instructions say my config file in .ssh looks like:

```
Host switchboard1.no.de
Port 34726 User node ForwardAgent yes
```

And I'm running on windows and using git bash

Thank you!

Comment: Seems a proxy issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399106/pushing-to-github-from-work-bad-file-number-error). Did you defined a `HOME` environment variable? (ie does `echo $HOME` works in your git bash session?)

Comment: Would you be able to run diagnostics mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587317/is-it-possible-to-transfer-the-git-sshkey-from-one-system-to-another/8589122#8589122 just to see where sash is failing?