# Reuse old GIT keys on new computer?

Tags: git

I've just bought a new computer. My old GIT keys are registered with a number of repositories so it would be convenient for me to reuse my private and public keys on this new machine. Is this safe to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it Possible to transfer the Git SSHKey from one system to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587317/is-it-possible-to-transfer-the-git-sshkey-from-one-system-to-another)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it's not safe to move a private key from one machine to another. It risks compromising the security of the private key, as it might get leaked in the process.

It would be better to create a new set of keys and register at the sites where you need. When you are ready to let go of the old machine, don't forget to revoke the old keys.

Comment: Downvoting for a whole lot of opinion with no support or evidence. _Having_ a private key represents a risk of compromise to the private key. That much is true. But copying it from one secure local location to another... not so much. Not unless we're talking about a pretty unusual, high-threat kind of situation. To be fair... it's not a _bad_ idea to use a machine migration as an opportunity to rotate your keys, right? Key rotation is good. But saying: "it's not safe to move a private key"? Nope. That's not a justifiable claim.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the machine you are using is safe then yes it is safe.  Make sure that whatever way you use to transfer the information is secure.

Have a look here for more info [Is it Possible to transfer the Git SSHKey from one system to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587317/is-it-possible-to-transfer-the-git-sshkey-from-one-system-to-another)