# git clone error

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to run the command "git clone xxx.git" and is showing the error:

```
ssh: connect to host port codebasehq.com 22: bad file number
```

What is happening? What kind of testing can I do to find out what the problem is?

Comment: windows server 2008 R2 Datacenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution of my problem was create the file in the CONFIG folder. ssh with the following contents:

> ```
> Host codebasehq.com
>     User git
>     Hostname ssh.codebasehq.com
>     PreferredAuthentications publickey
>     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>     Port 443
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you're at work, it's likely an error with your proxy (i.e. you don't have it setup correctly).

See:

[git SSH problem bad file number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-problem-bad-file-number)
and
[Another SSH problem bad file number post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399106/pushing-to-github-from-work-bad-file-number-error)