# facebook application shows error when cloning code

Tags: git, heroku, facebook-apps

Iam creating my first facebook application and I am using this Heroku (for hosting my app) for the first time as I was following the procedure provided in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook. While trying to fetch my app’s source code, the first step in instruction shows

```
ssh:connect to host heroku.com port 22: Bad file number  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I am novice in web and facebook application plz help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `Bad file number` error suggests you're behind a proxy or that connections are blocked some other way. Check out these two questions:

- [Git SSH error: "Connect to host: Bad file number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number)
- [pushing to github from work "Bad file number" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399106/pushing-to-github-from-work-bad-file-number-error)

Comment: Thanks Friism sir to reply, i am now out of proxy but when i try to git clone git@heroku.com:MyApp.git -o heroku command on my windows 7 it shows this message-                                              
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.132)' can't be established.                                                     RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?y
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: That error suggests a problem with your ssh keys, see here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103684/jenkins-fails-with-github-git-clone